# Repite el registro php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema al momento de asignar una tarea al usuario. Es que se repite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe de asignar el id del users.

Excepto el status **0**

el codigo que estoy implementando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que se quiere es que asigne al usuario el trabajo automaticamente evaluando la cantidad de trabajo que tiene y asi no sobre cargar de trabajo.

Cuento las veces que el `id_users` se repite en la tabla trabajo, el que tiene mas trabajo.

En la primera imagen se puede apreciar que el `id_users` *(9)* se repite 5 veces, como el registro llega hasta el 9 debe de empezar nuevamente en 1 y el `id_users` *(1)* debe de tener 5 para empezar el ciclo de nuevo.

---

Actualizacion de codigo:

```
    $sql7 = $db->query("SELECT id_propuestas,id_users,COUNT(id_users) FROM trabajo GROUP BY id_users HAVING COUNT(id_users) > 0 ORDER BY COUNT(id_users) DESC LIMIT 1");  

/// realiza el conteo los trabajo que tiene y indica cual es el id que tiene mas trabajo asignado.

    if ($row7 = $sql7->fetch_array()) {
        $idusers = $row7['id_users'];
        
        
    }
    
    $pro = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); 

// Para saber cual donde termina el id_users y no hace el largo if & elseif
    if ($rwx = $pro->fetch_array()) {
         $rx = $rwx['id']; 
    }
    if ($rx != $idusers) {
        $query7 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `status` = 1 AND id > '".$idusers."' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1");  

// me indica cual es el proximo numero que le sigue.
 
        if ($cnt7 = $query7->fetch_array()) { 
    
        }
    } elseif ($idusers == $rx) {
        $id2 = 1;
    } else {
     echo $id2;
    }
```

Lo que se desea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entendi que tratas de hacer. vos queres que eso que mostras al final se haga automaticamente en un query? partiendo de donde?

Comment: @gbianchi Un gusto, primero realizo el conteo de `id_users` luego realizo un recorrido a la table users para saber cuantos `id_users` estan disponible, consulto nuevamente la misma tabla de users para que me arroje el proximo id. Pero lo que me da es el id y me lo repire, quiero hacer lo que muestro en la ultima imagen

Comment: y en que momento asignas los usuarios?

Comment: Al momento de realizar el conteo `SELECT id_users,COUNT(id_users) FROM trabajo GROUP BY id_users HAVING COUNT(id_users) > 0 ORDER BY COUNT(id_users) DESC LIMIT 1` ,

 Me arroja el `id_users` que tiene mas trabajo asignado desde alli empiezo a trabajar

Comment: eso te devuelve un usuario.. y con eso que haces? no entiendo la logica de tu codigo y no lo que tratas de hacer con el mismo...

Comment: Guardo el valor del usuario en `$idusers` para realizar la ultima consulta del siguiente valor `SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 AND id > '".$idusers."' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1`

Comment: Todo eso, va a una sola linea de tu consulta.. por eso te digo.. no entiendo como esperas armar la tabla final... esperemos que alguien pueda entenderte...

Comment: como seria la consulta en una sola linea ? Estoy abierto a criticas amigo.